# Mean value theorem (integral version) for function with bounded variation

Tags: real-analysis, integration, bounded-variation, continuity

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) I find the following version of the integral mean value theorem (MVT) for continuous functions:

> If $f\colon[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then there exists a $c\in(a,b)$ such that $$\int_{a}^{b}f(t) \ \text{d}t=(b-a)f(c).$$

Now let $f\colon[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a map with bounded variation. This means that
$$\sup_{a=x_{1}<x_{2}<\ldots<x_{n}=b}\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}|f(x_{j})-f(x_{j+1})|<\infty.$$ According to [this link](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Function_of_bounded_variation) (proposition 5) the set of points of discontinuity of $f$ is at most countable. Does the integral MVT still hold?

Comment: Can't you always move the $y$-coordinate giving the average and make it false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No: there are even functions with one discontinuity for which this is false. For example, take the function $f$ which is $1$ for positve arguments and $-1$ otherwise. Then $f$ is nondecreasing, so has bounded variation, and never takes the value $0$, but
$$ \int_{-1}^{1} f = 0. $$